# Подмена redirect_uri в spring social при использовании SpringSocialConfigurer

Tags: spring, oauth, jwt

На проекте используется sso. Сервер авторизации находится за фронтом, но есть еще один сайт который его использует.
И придумали следующий flow:

```
1) Стучимся на бэк /auth/google и получаем ссылку на гугл для авторизации.
2) Подменяем redirect_uri на роут на фронте
3) Принимаем code на подмененном роуте
4) Отправляем code на /auth/google?code=received_code и все остальное
```

Это как бы решало все наши проблемы...В теории

Только вот проблемка возникла в state который формируется, как мы поняли на основе урлов. И получается что при подмене все инвалидируется и не работает.

Использовать контроллер не можем, потому что, после редиректа на /auth/google сразу же должен возвращаться jwt, без редиректа на главную. Ибо у нас ни кук, ни сессий, мы не можем прокинуть аутентификацию между запросами. А фильтр позволяет objectPostProcessor на successfull аутентификацию накинуть и сразу в response писать.